# System_Service_Exception on XP 64 bit

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, bsod

I have a computer which has been running XP 64-bit for several years with no hardware changes. One day I had a power surge and ever since then, I occasionally crash with a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) which says SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION. I also get a group of hex codes which look like:

```
0x0000003B (0x0000000080000003, 0xFFFFF80001026CD0, 0xFFFFFADF88E96D40, 0x000000000000000)
```

I ran a virus check with the latest Norton AntiVirus and no viruses were found.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Would a repair install of Windows XP SP3 be advisable?

Comment: Suggestion... replace with known-good RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923187/en-us

It's linked for W2k3 Server but works fine also for Xp x64 based.